# Check Facebook Connect Session on IOS

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, facebook

With the new Facebook library, FBSession object is disappeared.
How can i check if user has a valid session on his device immediately when he start the app without prompt to safari or uiwebview ?

The [facebook isSessionValid] method works on acccessToken but accessToken is set when app come back from safari (or inline uiwebview).

Is it possibleto check session using cookies ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a successful login, you want to save the access token and expiration date, like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_facebook.accessToken forKey:@"AccessToken"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_facebook.expirationDate forKey:@"ExpirationDate"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Then, when you load the app, you want to check if there is a saved token, like this:

```
_facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"[app_id]"];
_facebook.accessToken    = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"AccessToken"];
_facebook.expirationDate = (NSDate *) [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ExpirationDate"];
if (![_facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [_facebook authorize:_permissions delegate:self];
}
else {
    [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works great. There is a memory leak however in the _facebook initialization line (no need for retain).

Comment: I already logged in via facebook App. Then when i run my application it agains asked me for login? why? how to check if user already logged in Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it should automatically check if the user is logged in, wether through safari or the Facebook iPhone app. If the user is not logged in, then it will prompt using one of the applications above (default is safari if FB app is not installed, thats why the simulator opens FB in safari).

Comment: Thank you Danny Boy, yes it is checked through Safari ... but i need to not pass from safari/uiwebView etc to check if i'm logged. Example : I login the first time using safari/uiwebview, i close the app, than coming back to the app i would like that my user will be recognized with his name and facebook picture automatically

Comment: The Facebook object itself will check if the user is logged in using [self isSessionValid] when you attempt to perform an action. If the user is not logged in, it will take the appropriate action to log them in.

Comment: Looking at isSessionValid code, i figured it check on accessToken property and its expiration time . But this property is setted only after a login action (or a safari/uiwebview/FBapp prompt action). So i can't find a way to access this information without show at least a FB dialog.