# iOS FBConnent login popup issue

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, fbconnect

I'm using FBConnect on the iOS.
I tried to prevent the login popup by using:
- (void)viewDidLoad {

```
permissions = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                @"read_stream", @"offline_access", @"user_events", nil] retain];

FBtryAppDelegate *delegate = (FBtryAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

facebook = delegate.facebook;

[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
```

}

and every time it opens the login dialog and closes itself automatically without entering the details.

I don't want the dialog appear at all if the login is already exist.

what can I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the access token and the expiration date first. 
Then, you can check if the token is saved or not.
Please, [refer to this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596487/check-facebook-connect-session-on-ios/4598076#4598076).

Regards.